# Snowflake ODBC and VARIANT data type

Tags: odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

Using odbctest and Snowflake 64-bit ODBC driver for Windows:

Created a table in snowflake using this DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "SFDEST"."QAUSER"."BT14726" 
("VARCHAR_10_COL" VARCHAR (10),
 "VARCHAR_4000_COL" VARCHAR (4000) ,
 "CHAR_10_COL" CHAR (10) ,
 "CLOB_COL" VARIANT,
 "ROWID" CHAR (18)  NOT NULL )
```

Then attempted to prepare an insert statement:
SQL attempted:

```
INSERT INTO "SFDEST"."QAUSER"."BT14726" 
("VARCHAR_10_COL",
 "VARCHAR_4000_COL",
 "CHAR_10_COL",
 "ROWID",
 "CLOB_COL")
VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

But this error was returned:

> Prepare of destination insert statement failed. SQL compilation error:
>   Expression type does not match column data type, expecting VARIANT but
>   got VARCHAR(1) for column CLOB_COL

This is the relevant portion of odbc trace:

> sqdrsvc         3dfc-52bc          ENTER SQLPrepare 
>                           HSTMT               0x000000435C961620
>                           UCHAR *             0x000000435D262720 [     140] "INSERT INTO "SFDEST"."QAUSER"."BT14726" ("VARCHAR_10_COL",
>   "VARCHAR_4000_COL", "CHAR_10_COL", "ROWID", "CLOB_COL")  VALUES ( ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?) "
>                           SDWORD                   140
>
> sqdrsvc         3dfc-52bc          EXIT  SQLPrepare  with return code
>   -1 (SQL_ERROR)
>                           HSTMT               0x000000435C961620
>                           UCHAR *             0x000000435D262720 [     140] "INSERT INTO "SFDEST"."QAUSER"."BT14726" ("VARCHAR_10_COL",
>   "VARCHAR_4000_COL", "CHAR_10_COL", "ROWID", "CLOB_COL")  VALUES ( ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?) "
>                           SDWORD                   140
>                           DIAG [22000] SQL compilation error: Expression type does not match column data type, expecting VARIANT but got
>   VARCHAR(1) for column CLOB_COL (2023)

Comment: This post describes everything except for the actual bind variables being passed into the INSERT statement.  What is the value of CLOB_COL being inserted?  If it's JSON as a string, you need to use PARSE_JSON() function to make it JSON first.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string that is formatted as a valid JSON blob, you need to use PARSE_JSON to convert it into an actual variant type so that SnowFlake can recognize it as such.

Probably something like this:

```
INSERT INTO "SFDEST"."QAUSER"."BT14726" 
("VARCHAR_10_COL",
 "VARCHAR_4000_COL",
 "CHAR_10_COL",
 "ROWID",
 "CLOB_COL")
VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, PARSE_JSON(?))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Our developer says "ODBC does not require the variables to be bound prior to the prepare." so this is still an open question.

Comment: I think the question comes down to the values of your variables that are getting bound. Can you add examples of those to your question above?

Comment: Also... Are you still getting the same error with this change? If it's different, can you provide the new error message ?